# Convergence of indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, functions, continuity

Let $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that: $x_k\to x$, $k\to+\infty$. Is true that:
$\chi_{B_R(x_k)}\to\chi_{B_R(x)}$, $k\to+\infty$, pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^n$? In this case can you give me a rigorous proof of this fact?

Comment: is $B_R$ the open ball of radius $R$?

Comment: Yes, $B_R(y)$ is the open ball of radius R and centre $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On $\mathbb R,$ does $\chi_{B(1/k,1)} \to \chi_{B(0,1)}$ everywhere? No because $\chi_{B(0,1)}(1)=0,$ while $\chi_{B(1/k,1)}(1)=1$ for all $k.$

---

**Added later**: The OP asks if we have $\chi_{B(x_k,R)} \to \chi_{B(x,R)}$ a.e. The answer is yes. First fix $y\in B(x,R).$ Then $|y-x|=R-\epsilon.$ For large $k$ we will have $|x-x_k|<\epsilon/2.$ For such $k,$

$$|y-x_k|\le |y-x|  + |x-x_k| <R-\epsilon+\epsilon/2 = R-\epsilon/2.$$

Thus for large $k,$ $y\in B(x_k,R),$ which implies $1= \chi_{B(x_k,R)}(y)=\chi_{B(x,R)}(y).$ So for any fixed $y \in B(x,R),$ we get pointwise convergence.

A similar argument shows that if $|y-x|>R,$ then we have pointwise convergence at $y$ (to $0$).

Letting $C$ be the set where pointwise convergence holds, we see $ B(x,R)\subset C\subset \{|y|>R\}.$ So the only set where we don't have pointwise convergence is a subset of $\partial B(x,R),$ a set of measure $0.$

Comment: But is true that $\chi_{B_R(x_k)}\to\chi_{B_R(x)}$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$? In this case can you give a me rigorous proof of this fact please ?

Comment: Done. $\,\,\,\,$

Comment: Ok, very clear. Now i want prove that $\chi_{B_R(x_k)}\leq\chi_{B_{2R}(x)}$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $k$ large. I have tried to use the same idea but it seems to me doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: In fact, $\chi_{B(x_k,R)}\le \chi_{B(x,2R)}$ everywhere for $k$ large. Proof: Suppose $|x_k -x| <R.$ Let $y\in B(x_k,R).$ Then 

$$|y-x|\le |y-x_k|+|x_k-x|<R + R=2R.$$

So for such $k,$ $y\in B(x,2R).$ For these $k$ we therefore have $\chi_{B(x_k,R)}\le \chi_{B(x,2R)}$ everywhere.